# Extract rows from a data.frame based on common values with a list

Tags: r, list, filtering

I'm looking for an easy way for filtering rows from a data.frame, based on a list of numeric sequences.

Here's a exemple:

My initial data frame:

```
data <- data.frame(x=c(0,1,2,0,1,2,3,4,5,12,2,0,10,11,12,13),y="other_data")
```

My list:

```
list1 <- list(1:5,10:13)
```

My goal is to keep only the rows from "data" which contains exactly the same numeric sequences of "list1" as in the "x" column of "data".
So the output data.frame should be:

```
finaldata <- data.frame(x=c(1:5,10:13),y="other_data")
```

Any ideas for doing this?

Comment: what is the desired output if the column `y` contains `c("other_data", "data", rep("other_data",14))` ?

Comment: Please use `data <- data.frame(x=c(0,1,2,0,1,2,3,4,5,12,2,0,10,11,12,13),y=letters[1:16])` as the example and show the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started with a custom function to get the subset for one sequence, then it's easy to extend with lapply.

```
#function that takes sequence and a vector
#and returns indices of vector that have complete sequence
get_row_indices<- function(sequence,v){
  #get run lengths of whether vector is in sequence
  rle_d <- rle(v %in% sequence)
  #test if it's complete, so both v in sequence and length of 
  #matches is length of sequence
  select <- rep(length(sequence)==rle_d$lengths &rle_d$values,rle_d$lengths)

  return(select)

}


#add row ID to data to show selection
data$row_id <- 1:nrow(data)
res <- do.call(rbind,lapply(list1,function(x){
  return(data[get_row_indices(sequence=x,v=data$x),])
}))

res

> res
    x          y row_id
5   1 other_data      5
6   2 other_data      6
7   3 other_data      7
8   4 other_data      8
9   5 other_data      9
13 10 other_data     13
14 11 other_data     14
15 12 other_data     15
16 13 other_data     16
```

Comment: Thanks for you help Heroka! your custom function works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `rollapply` from `zoo`:

```
library(zoo)

ind = lapply(list1, function(x) {
    n = length(x)
    which(rollapply(data$x, n, function(y) all(y==x))) + 0:(n-1)
})

data[unlist(ind),]
#x          y
#5   1 other_data
#6   2 other_data
#7   3 other_data
#8   4 other_data
#9   5 other_data
#13 10 other_data
#14 11 other_data
#15 12 other_data
#16 13 other_data
```

Comment: I know this kind of thanks comment is discouraged, but I was struggling on how to make it with rollapply for a while, so thanks for it

Comment: Np I learned a lot from other using unknown (from my point of view) function as well!

Answer (score 1):

```
extract_fun <- function(x, dat){
  # Index where the sequences start
  ind <- which(dat == x[1])
  # Indexes (within dat) where the sequence should be
  ind_seq <- lapply(ind, seq, length.out = length(x))
  # Extract the values from dat at the position
  dat_val <- mapply(`[`, list(dat), ind_seq)
  # Check if values within dat == those in list1
  i <- which(as.logical(apply(dat_val, 2, all.equal, x))) # which one is equal?
  # Return the correct indices
  ind_seq[[i]]
}
```

Get the indices per Item in `list1` and combine them to the needed indices

```
all_ind <- do.call(c, lapply(list1, extract_fun, data$x))
data[all_ind,]
```

Result:

```
    x          y
5   1 other_data
6   2 other_data
7   3 other_data
8   4 other_data
9   5 other_data
13 10 other_data
14 11 other_data
15 12 other_data
16 13 other_data
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `match2` goes through each `x` value and checks it and the next n values against a vector of length n. Then uses `Reduce` to create a sequence for indexing.

```
match2 <- function(vec) {
  start <- which(sapply(1:nrow(data), function(i) all(data$x[i:(i+length(vec)-1)] == vec)))
  Reduce(':', c(start,start+length(vec)-1))
}
```

With this, we can use an apply function to repeat the process for each `list1`.

```
s <- sapply(list1, match2)
data[unlist(s),]
#     x          y
# 5   1 other_data
# 6   2 other_data
# 7   3 other_data
# 8   4 other_data
# 9   5 other_data
# 13 10 other_data
# 14 11 other_data
# 15 12 other_data
# 16 13 other_data
```